# Need Regex to parse String

Tags: regex, vim

Using a regular expression, I want to parse a String like "DOCID = 1234567 THIS IS TEST" and remove the remaining String after the numbers.

How can I do this using the VIM editor?

Comment: Guys, does the language matter? its a regex question, you should ask waht regex engine he is using.

Comment: @Antonioo: yes, it does, not the regex itself but for the way to use it.

Comment: @M42 the way to use it is dependant on the language in which you are programming - in which you are supposed to be comfortable enough to take any regex and use it with your language. Unless you mean "the way to use it" ie to copy-paste it without understanding what it is.

Comment: @Antonioo: Some softs uses special regexes, VIM is in that case, you need to escape some characters in order to make the regex work. I answered for VIM.

Comment: Regex is a language, it is based on automata theory, there is no special regexes, there is just applications of the same ideas. Escaping here and there is language-dependent, not regex dependent. Shall we for every stackoverflow question answer in all possible languages?

Comment: the answer becomes more readable to the questioner, if it's in the language he's intending to use

Comment: @Antonioo The set of regular languages is indeed defined by automata theory, but you should know that the regex capabilities of most languages are actually equivalent to pushdown automata or full turing machines. If a particular language offers a regex construct that makes matching the pattern easier (and falls outside what a finite state machine can do), it's important that the answer reflect that.

Comment: @TylerHobbs point taken and noted.

Answer (score 4):

In Perl:

```
$str =~ s/(= \d+).*$/$1/;
```

In php:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(= \d+).*$/', "$1", $str);
```

Comment: To select the preceding group shouldn't it be `(.*= \d+)`?

Comment: @slashmais: No, it's not required because it replaces all the match by the first group.

Answer (score 2):

That will do the job:

```
:%s/\d\+\zs.*
```

Explanation:

- `%` use the whole buffer, you can omit this if you want to change current line only
- `s` the substitute command
- `\d\+` match as many numbers
- `\zs` set the start of match here
- `.*` everything else
- you can omit the replacement string because you want to delete the match

Answer (score 1):

In VIM, in command mode (press ESC), write :

```
:s/\([^0-9]\+[0-9]\+\).*/\1/
```

This will do the job.
If you want to do all replacement possible, then :

```
:s/\([^0-9]\+[0-9]\+\).*/\1/g
```

Answer (score 0):

in java `string.replaceFirst("(= \\d+).*$","\\1");`